# can some trace the location of the code below attached, thru google map?

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Lot number in santo tomas pangasinan Philippines we need to check and verify the details for us to properly know the exact location of the land we are looking for.[image: 1]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers are directions and distances.

Example: `N 59° 07′ E, 9.57 m` means:

1. Face **N**orth
2. Turn 59° 07′ **E**ast
3. Walk 9.57 meter

Repeat these steps for all 4 lines in your document.

Now all you need to find out is where to start from, i.e. `point 1`. I guess that information should be in the same document.

Note: I'm not familiar with Philippines land survey methods, but the values look similar to how parcels in the US are sometimes described, see [here](http://www.merebrookllc.com/reading-descriptions.html) for more details.